# PHP Error when insert value into database

Tags: php

Here is the code:

```
function user_register($user) {

    $link = db_connect();
    $query = sprintf('INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_password, user_email, display_name, register_date, active_date, user_reputation, user_status)
        VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", %d, %d)',
        mysql_real_escape_string($user['username']),
        mysql_real_escape_string(md5($user['password'])),
        mysql_real_escape_string($user['email']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($user['name']),
        mysql_real_escape_string(get_current_time()),
        mysql_real_escape_string(get_current_time()),
        1,
        1);

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die();
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($link);
    if ( $num_rows == 1 ) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is error message u getting ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not specifying the error you're getting, I'll just guess that `mysql_num_rows` doesn't like you passing it a boolean value instead of a resource. For this, please read the manual:

> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, `mysql_query()` returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on error.
>
> Use `mysql_num_rows()` to find out how many rows were returned for a SELECT statement or **`mysql_affected_rows()` to find out how many rows were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.**

http://php.net/mysql_query
http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows

You also don't need to use `mysql_free_result` since you're not getting any *results*, just a boolean `true`/`false`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the double quotes in your query to single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_password, user_email, display_name, register_date, active_date, user_reputation, user_status)
    VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%d')
```